how to add shapefile (basin boundary) to tiff file (iran map) in python
I have Iran's rainfall zoning map in TIF format and I get the output using the following code. But the border of the basins is not clear.
how to add shapefile (basin boundary) to tiff file (iran map) in python
how to add shapefile (basin boundary) to tiff file (iran map) in python
from pyidw import idw
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize


fig, ax, cbar = idw.show_map(
input_raster="Anomaly (2051-2075)_SSP126.tif",
colormap="brg",
image_size=1.5,
return_figure=True)

image = ax.get_images()[0]
image.set_clim(10, -7)
cbar.update_normal(image)

ax.set_title("Maximum temperature map")
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude")
ax.set_ylabel("Latitude")

plt.show()


Consider using generic mapping tools (gmt). It has CLI tools and bindings for Python, Matlab and some other languages.

I used it a fortran program.
